# eglInitialize failure using ANGLE dll from python 64 bits

Tags: python, dll, opengl-es, ctypes

I've been using the ANGLE dlls for a while to run OpenGLES2.0 code on windows from 32 bit python (pi3d module) However I can't get it to work with 64 bits. I have [compiled the libraries](https://github.com/paddywwoof/pi3d_windll) and at one stage, on a different laptop to which I don't have access now, it did get further than this. This is a stripped down version of the code that reproduces the point where it currently stops.

```
import ctypes
import pygame
import os

EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY = 0
EGL_NO_DISPLAY = 0
EGL_TRUE = 1

pygame.init()
d = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.OPENGL)
info = pygame.display.Info()
width, height = info.current_w, info.current_h

#path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/42.0.2311.152"
#path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\Chrome\\Application\\42.0.2311.135"
path = "" # compiled ANGLE dll files in same directory
d3dcompiler = ctypes.WinDLL(os.path.join(path, "d3dcompiler_47.dll"))
opengles = ctypes.WinDLL(os.path.join(path, "libglesv2.dll"))
openegl = ctypes.WinDLL(os.path.join(path, "libegl.dll"))
display = openegl.eglGetDisplay(EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
assert display != EGL_NO_DISPLAY #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
r = openegl.eglInitialize(display, None, None)
print('eglInitialize() returned {}'.format(r))
assert r == EGL_TRUE             #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a 32-bit integer is given as an argument or expected as the type for the returned value instead of a 64-bit unsigned integer. This happens commonly for pointer values (handles) since 64-bit windows has 32-bit integers and 64-bit pointers. Defining `argtypes` and `restypes` attributes may help, or at least help to spot the problems.

```
import ctypes.wintypes as wt

openegl.elgGetDisplay.argtypes = [wt.HDC]
openegl.elgGetDisplay.restype = c_void_p

openegl.eglInitialize.argtypes = [c_void_p, POINTER(c_int32), POINTER(c_int32)]
openegl.eglInitialize.restype = c_uint
```

then

```
display = openegl.eglGetDisplay(None)
assert display.value is not None
r = openegl.eglInitialize(display, None, None)
```

might work (I don't have that library installed so I can't verify).

Comment: Thanks for this help. That has done the trick. Liberal specification of argtypes with void pointers has got it working on 64 bit windows. I just have to check that it still works on a 32 bit system. (Note to self: resort to stackoverflow a bit sooner in future)